# How do I modify the values of mutableStateMapOf?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, desktop-application

I've got a field of type `mutableStateMapOf`:

```kotlin
var dataPool by mutableStateMapOf("archive" to true, "pending" to true)
```

and I'd like to modify its values via a `Checkbox` so I tried this:

```kotlin
 Checkbox(checked = true, onCheckedChange = {viewModel.dataPool["archive"]=it})
```

However, Kotlin shows me that `dataPool` is a `boolean`. How comes? I thought I initialized it as `map`. I don't follow what's happening here. Usually when you initialize one of the `mutableState`s it has the type I use as a parameter, but why not this time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's really strange why it has a delegation that returns a Boolean and throws exception when you try to read it on compose version 1.5.4. And doesn't let you add brackets too.

You can get `SnapshotStateMap<String, Boolean>` from `mutableStateMapOf` with `=` not `by`

```
val dataPool = remember {
    mutableStateMapOf("archive" to true, "pending" to false)
}
```

Comment: By the way mutableStateListOf doesn't have a delegation like mutableStateMapOf of.  What's the point of having this delegation for mutableStateMapOf?

Comment: Indeed, it works with a `=`! That's crazy! Btw, what coincidence. I was just studying your another answer about Checkboxes with clickable Text so you'll get even more points ;-]

Comment: Thanks. This was a very good question as well, i upvoted even before you did:) I'm genuinely curious why it has delegation that doesn't work